# How to know when the disk is ready after calling flush() on the stream?

Tags: python

I have a file called `foo.txt` with a 1B rows.

I want to apply an operation on each row that produces 10 new rows. Output is expected to be around 10B rows.

To increase the speed and the IO, `foo.txt` is on DiskA and `bar.txt` DiskB (different drives - physically speaking).

DiskB is going to be the limiting factor. Because there's a lot of rows to write, I added a large buffer when I write to DiskB.

*My question is: When I call flush() on diskB, the buffer of the file handler will flush it to the hard drive. It seems to be a non-blocking call since the command returns but I can still see that the disk is writing and its busy indicator is 100%. After a couple of seconds, the indicator goes back to 0%. Is there a way in python to wait for the disk to finish? Ideally, I would like flush() to be a blocking call. The only solution I see now is to add arbitrary sleep() and hopes that the disk is ready.*

Here's a snippet to show visually (It's a bit more complicated in practice as `bar.txt` is not just one file but thousands of files so the IO efficiency is very poor):

```py
with open('bar.txt', 'w', buffering=100 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) as w:
    with open('foo.txt') as r:
        for line in r:
            # writes each line of foo 10 times in bar.
            for i in range(10):
                w.write(line)
            # w.flush()
```

Comment: Philippe, you might comment on my answer or enhance your question to explain better what you try to achieve, and also give more information like which OS you're running on. what filesystem you're writing the file to.

This should help you to get a better answer. 
I think I gave a decent shot without having enough details.

Comment: Linux system. Ext4 filesystem. We read from one disk and we write onto another (distinct) disk. It's asymmetric meaning that we read 10GB and we wrote like 100GB to the other disk. Hence the problem. If it was symmetric, like read 1GB and write 1GB, then it would not be a problem. My question is more how to somehow make this read - write smoother. Thanks a lot for your help btw!

Comment: you might check, whether journaling is enabled on this disk and consider disabling it. However you must be able to accept the consequences of giving up journalling for this disk in your system.

Comment: Did you find a way to increase throughput? If yes How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several issues.

- `"when the disk is ready"` had to be defined very clearly.
- your OS, file system and configuration might be important
- your exact use case might be important

To know when data is written to the disk will have different answers depending on the OS and the file system and the OS/filesystem configuration.

Please note that following situations are not (or might not be) identical:

- to know when your process can write the next bytes without blocking
- know when another process can read the bytes from a file (might be after a flush)
- know when the OS wrote the last byte to the disk controller (when all write caches are flushed)
- know when you could cut the power without losing data / when data was really written to the disk (when your disk controller flushed out its buffers)

The main question is really, why exactly you have to know when the last byte has been written?

If your motivation is performance, then perhaps it's just good enough to have two threads:

- a reading and processing thread who places the data to write in a Queue (`threading.Queue`) with a max amount of entries. That means, when the queue reaches a certain size the reading/processing thread will be blocked
- a writing thread that just reads from the queue and writes to disk.

If above is the case and you never used `threading` and `threading Queue` I can enhance my answer. Just tell me.

However if you say, that writing / flushing is not / never blocking, then
this wouldn't help.

Just for fun you could implement above threads and check with a third thread periodically the size of the queue to see whether writing is really the bottle neck. If it were, then your FIFO should be (almost) full most of the time.

**Comment after first feedback:**

Youre running on linux with an SSD drive with ext4 to write to.

It seems but I'm still not sure, that a more representative example than the one in the question would be a script just writing to N files in an alternating manner with different  data rates.

I still have the impression, that increased write buffer sizes and letting the OS do the rest should give you a performance, that is difficult to improve by manual interventions.

Disabling journaling on the disk might improve performance though

```
writers = []
writers.append((open("f1", "w", buffering=100 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE), "a")
writers.append((open("f2", "w", buffering=100 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE), "b" * 10000)
writers.append((open("f3", "w", buffering=100 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE), "c" * 100)
...
writers.append((open("f1000", "w", buffering=100 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE), "a" * 200)

for n in range(x):
    # Normally this is where you would read data from a file, 
    # analyse the data and write some data to one or multiple writers
    # as a very approximate simulation I just write to the writers in 
    # data chunks in alternating order

    for writer, data in writers:  
        writer.write(data)

        # this is the question:
        # Can I write lines of the following nature, that will increase 
        # the write rate?
        if some_condition:
            writer.flush()
```

Would this model your problem? (I know in reality the write rates of a writer won't be constant and the order in which writers would write are random)

I have the impression I am missing something.
Why should these flushes accelerate anything?
This is an SSD. It doesn't have any mechanical delays for waiting, that the disk spun to a certain place. the buffering will only write to a file if you have 'enough data worth being written'.

What I'm also confused about is, that you say `flush()` is non blocking.

A buffered write is just putting data in a buffer and calling flush() when the buffer is full, this means, that write() would also be non blocking.

If everything is non blocking, than your process  would loose 0 time for writing and there wouldn't be anything to optimize.

So I guess, that write() and flush() are blocking calls, but not blocking in the way you expect them to block. They are probably blocking until the OS accepted the data for writing, (which does not mean, the data has been written)
The real writes to the disk will happen whenever the OS decides to do so.
There are write caches involved, the disk controller might add some other layers of write caching / write reordering.

in order to check this you can add debug code around every write of following kind.

```
import time
global t_max = 0


...
# this had to be done for every `write` or `flush` 
# or at least for some representative calls of them
t0 = time.time()
bla.write()
t = time.time() - t0
t_max = max(t_max, t)
```

You will probably have a t_max, that indicates, that .write is blocking
....

Comment: - "when the disk is ready" had to be defined very clearly. It can be when the disk usage is 0% i.e IDLE.
your OS, file system and configuration might be important: Linux, ext4 file system, 2 SSD drives. Motivation is to have something fast. Performance matters in this setup.
why exactly you have to know when the last byte has been written? I would like a blocking flush() call to make sure the disk on which I write has finished writing and is ready to write again. The result is because I read from one large file but I write to many small files (10GB and 100GB write to smtg like 1000 files).

Comment: So because the write operation is fragmented, the operation is less efficient and the disk on which I write is easily "drowned", especially because it's an asymmetric Read/Write set up.

Comment: Is your scenario:

Read from one file from one disk, process data and write then in an alternating manner to multiple files on another disk (linux, SSD, ext4) these multiple files have different write rates. There is a max of N (what is N?, 10, 100, 1000, ??) files to write to opened at the same time.

Application is single threaded and all writes happen in the same thread.

You're looking for a strategy to accelerate the writes.

And now I don't really understand:
You hope to increase the overall performance by adding flush and sleep statements (or is it reordering the writes?)

Comment: Enhanced the answer. I'm less and less sure I understand how you want to use flush to accelerate your code